# How to change a rectangle's area based on it's 4 coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a rectangle with it's 4 bounds/coordinates on a Cartesian plane. Lets say I want to make the rectangle twice as big. How do i find the new coordinates?

[Example, Dotted lines are the new lines after growing the area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKtzv.jpg)

In the example image above, the original coordinates are (5, 10) (6, 9) (5, 8) (4, 9). If i wanted to grow the rectangle an arbitrary number like 1.2 times, the new coordinates would be
(5, 11) (7, 9) (5, 7) (3, 9). How do i find these new coordinates mathematically?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: What does "twice as big" mean? That's an important question.

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

To double the area, multiply each of the four bounds by $\sqrt{2}$.  That will multiply both side lengths by $\sqrt{2}$, and multiply the area by $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=2$.

---

Example:  $x=2, x=4$ and $y=5, y=10$.  Current area = $(4-2)\times (10-5)=2\times 5=10$.

Multiply everything by $\sqrt{2}$.  The new values will be $x=2\sqrt{2}, x=4\sqrt{2}$ and $y=5\sqrt{2}, y=10\sqrt{2}$.  The new area will be $(4\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{2})\times (10\sqrt{2}-5\sqrt{2})=(2\sqrt{2})\times (5\sqrt{2})=10\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=20$.

---

Second example: $(5, 10) (6, 9) (5, 8) (4, 9) \to (5\sqrt{2}, 10\sqrt{2}) (6\sqrt{2}, 9\sqrt{2}) (5\sqrt{2}, 8\sqrt{2}) (4\sqrt{2}, 9\sqrt{2})$

All four side lengths (in this example not horizontal/vertical) will be $\sqrt{2}$ longer, so the area will be twice as big.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @JaspreetSingh sure. Say your have rectangle who's sides are length $x$ and $y$ with area $A$. Then the rectangle with sides of length $\sqrt{2}x$ and $\sqrt{2}y$ has area $2A$.

Comment: But i have the 4 coordinates which I want to make changes to.

Comment: @vadim123 but this will displace the rectangle right? How can i resize around the center without displacing the rectangle?

Comment: Okay, the question was about resizing, not about resizing while keeping the center fixed.  After you're done, move the rectangle so that its center is wherever you want it to be.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't mention that in the question. I only have the 4 corner coordinates. How can i move it back? I don't have the center.